# Disable console output from the from the OPAL project?

Tags: scala, static-analysis, opal-framework

I'm using the OPAL framework to implement static analyses. I wondered if it is possible to suppress the console output of the framework which is printed on the console while execution. The following shows a part of the output.

```
...
[info][OPAL] Bytecod Representation - Development Build (asserstions are enables) 
[info][project configuration] the JDK is part of the analysis
[warn][project configuration] supertype information incomplete
...
```

I found that OPAL has several LogLevels (i.e. WARN, INFO, ERROR) but I couldn't find a way to specify the logging granularity. I'm really interested in warnings and errors but I would like to suppress the (massive) output at info level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now I figured out that it is possible to suppress the console output of OPAL. The OPAL logging mechanism uses several `LogContext` objects. It exists one `GlobalLogContext` and one `LogContext` per available `Project`. Since both are independent it is necessary to silence both types.

The first context is used for every logging event which does not happen in the context of a specific project whereas the project-specific context is used to log messages in a given context.

The `OPALLogger.update(...)` method can be used to update the Logger that is used for a LogContext. With this method, it is possible to associate a new Logger with a LogContext. If you are running OPAL with the command line, a `ConsoleOPALLogger` can be used as follows.

```
val project = ...    
OPALLogger.updateLogger(project.logContext, new ConsoleOPALLogger(true, org.opalj.log.Error))
OPALLogger.updateLogger(GlobalLogContext, new ConsoleOPALLogger(true, org.opalj.log.Error))
```